# iCloud storage, Backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos

none of my photos are available anymore , they dont open properly (all blurry) and it says its because i dont have enough icloud storage, i went to check it through my iphone but it tells me "unable to load storage info" (i tried both on wifi and data) so i can do nothing about it. I checked with pc and i have 2GB free. I wanted to know how I can get my photos back or at least transfer them to my pc.

Comment: Can you access them at full resolution on your computer?

Comment: This is one of the most annoying features of mac. They effectively steal your photos to "back them up", then deny you access to them unless you buy more icloud storage. Many people don't even realize this has happened, so they just permanently  lose their photos, maintaining only a preview.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> Tap on your name -> Tap on iCloud -> Tap on Storage or Manage Storage and then you'll be able to see how much "iCloud storage you have available.

Your iPhone storage is different from your iCloud. What you can do though is while you are in iCloud settings, go to Photos (in iCloud) then put a check next to "Download and keep originals". That will make sure the photos save in full quality. This will also eat up your iPhone storage depending on how many photos you have.